# Jquery each selector index does not increment

Tags: jquery, each

**I have following html div**

```
<div id="sentencesDiv">
</div>
```

**I have following jquery code :**

```
mydiv =jQuery('<div/>', {
                id : key,
                text: sentences[key], // key of sentence BDM4 is here 
            }).appendTo('#sentencesDiv');

    $('#sentencesDiv').each(function(index,value){
                        jQuery('<input/>', {
                            class : "ch",
                            type : "checkbox"
                        }).appendTo(mydiv);

                        jQuery('<img/>', {
                            class : "correctWrong",
                            alt : 'image',
                            width : '42px',
                            height :'42px',
                            id : 'img'+index
                        }).appendTo(mydiv);

            });
```

when i try to add id :

```
'img'+index
```

it always adds **'img0' as id** .
I dont understand what is the problem

I want an output like this

```
<div id="sentencesDiv">

<div id="somekey1">
<input type="checkbox" />
<img class="correctWrong" alt="image" style="width: 42px; height: 42px;" id="img0">
</div>

<div id="somekey2">
<input type="checkbox" />
<img class="correctWrong" alt="image" style="width: 42px; height: 42px;" id="img1">
</div>

<div id="somekey3">
<input type="checkbox" />
<img class="correctWrong" alt="image" style="width: 42px; height: 42px;" id="img2">
</div>

......
</div>
```

**Also i am confused when to use**

```
$('#sentencesDiv').each(function(index,value){});
```

**and**

```
$('#sentencesDiv div').each(function(index,value){});
```

Comment: please share jsfiddle of this

Comment: using `$('#sentencesDiv').each` would loop just 1 time because the id `#sentencesDiv` is unique, I think you may have to use the later `$('#sentencesDiv div').each`

Comment: From your code, it definitely won't be `$('#sentencesDiv').each`. It is most likely to be the second case but you haven't shown how you are generating the `<div id="somekeyx">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.each()` operation for a selector such as "#sentencesDiv" will run the inner function at most once, which is why `index` is always zero.

You can move the code out of the `.each()` altogether and then have the image id depend on the `key` variable instead of `index`.

```
var mydiv =jQuery('<div/>', {
    id : key,
    text: sentences[key], // key of sentence BDM4 is here 
})

jQuery('<input/>', {
    class : "ch",
    type : "checkbox"
}).appendTo(mydiv);

jQuery('<img/>', {
    class : "correctWrong",
    alt : 'image',
    width : '42px',
    height :'42px',
    id : 'img' + key
}).appendTo(mydiv);

mydiv.appendTo('#sentencesDiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

The element which comes multiple time use each on it

so use this to achieve your requirement

```
  $('#sentencesDiv div').each(function(index,value){
                    jQuery('<input/>', {
                        class : "ch",
                        type : "checkbox"
                    }).appendTo(mydiv);

                    jQuery('<img/>', {
                        class : "correctWrong",
                        alt : 'image',
                        width : '42px',
                        height :'42px',
                        id : 'img'+index
                    }).appendTo(mydiv);
        });
```

Because you want to add your code in `<div>` in side `#sentencesDiv`  element

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
// for all direct child elements of #sentencesDiv 
$('#sentencesDiv > div').each(function(index,value){
     // your code goes here
});
```